Searching for the commentary of Rabbi Menahem ben Simeon of Posqui​è​res to Jeremiah and Ezekiel
Over Pesach I was taking a deeper dive into the Haggadah and saw an unusual reference in the Koren Tanach from Rabbi Adin Even Yisroel Steinsaltz to the commentary from Rabbi Menachem ben Shimon (Parshat Bo note 97).
I was unfamiliar with this name and researched further to discover that he was a Rishon from Provence. According to the biographical information he wrote a complete commentary on the Tanach, but we only have his commentary to Jeremiah and Ezekiel remaining today.
I would like to acquire a printed copy of his commentaries to add to my personal  library. Does anyone out there know where I can find it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Apparently it was recently claimed that his commentary on Mishlei has also been preserved.

This dissertation seems to me to be the only printed version. I can't access it online, but people in the USA might have access via Hathitrust here. The dissertation is in German but according to the first link there are two Hebrew appendices. Presumably (though not certainly) these are the two commentaries. Some libraries offer printing services, so that's a possibility. In any case, manuscripts of the commentaries can be accessed via the NLI website.

There's also another dissertation written on the first 25 chapters of the commentary on Yirmiyahu, see here. I don't know whether the author included the full or even partial commentary as an appendix.

@Harel13 Thanks so much for your help. I was able to access a PDF of the German publication. It is only fragments of the two commentaries. More significantly, it doesn't go to chapter 30 of Jeremiah and that is what Steinsaltz is quoting. What is "NLI" that you are referencing?

NLI- National Library of Israel. Type in מנחם בן שמעון מפוסקיר and you'll find the relevant manuscripts.

There appears to be a complete manuscript from the 14th century at the National Library of France in Paris that is almost 300 pages long. It said that I could download a PDF of the entire manuscript for personal use and looked like it was doing it. But nothing ultimately downloaded.

The site's been having a lot of problems since the upgrades last fall. Keep trying, maybe refresh the page a few times.

I tried using a different browser and it seems to have worked. I got two different manuscripts in PDF of the complete commentary to both Jeremiah and Ezekiel. Thanks so much for the lead. He was a student of Rabbi Yosef Kimchi who was the father of the Radak. I can't believe this hasn't been published. It looks incredible.

You're very welcome. It's possible that there are other manuscripts out there. Try checking out also the Ktiv website, which is an NLI project but sometimes gets better results than the main site.  I have also wondered many times in the last few years about a number of manuscript works that have yet to be published, including ones that have had papers and/or books written about them. But publication does take time and money.
